# Android Studio Live Templates

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, live-templates

I have `KotlinData` and want to generate `val domain` with getter function. There can be a different amount of the variables.
I want to create Live Template for code generation but I can't find how to manage dynamic variables count.

What can I use in "Live Templates" for dynamic class variables?

```
data class KotlinData(
    private val val1: Int,
    private val val2: Double,
    private val val3: String,
    ....
    private val valN: String 
) {
    val domain
        get() = KotlinDataDomain(
            val1 = val1,
            val2 = val2,
            val3 = val3,
            ....
            valN = valN
        )
}
```

Comment: You can't use a live template for that; you need to write a small plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a groovy script in which you can do any logic you want with your file and after that link that groovy script with the newly created Live template:https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000661530-Advanced-Live-Templates-with-Groovy-scripting

But yes, maybe it is better and faster to write a small plugin.